# Como eu faço para formatar o texto digitado no input sem alterar o valor?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Galera, estou com um problema nesse trecho do código que não consigo resolver de nenhuma maneira. No caso, os dois primeiros input recebem valores que são somados e essa soma aparece no ultimo input com o id dinheiroDivergência, até ai tudo certo.

```
              <td><b>Dinheiro</b></td>
              <!-- Dinheiro - Valor Encontrado -->
              <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="dve" min="1" value="0" onkeyup="Calcular()" onmouseout="Calcular()" onkeydown="Calcular()"/></td>
              <!-- Dinheiro - Sistema -->
              <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="ds" min="1" value="0" onkeyup="Calcular()" onmouseout="Calcular()" onkeydown="Calcular()"/></td>
              <!-- Dinheiro - Divergência -->
              <td><input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" id="dinheiroDivergencia" disabled></td>
```

O meu problema está na formatação dos input, eu gostaria que ao usuário digitar os números formatassem automaticamente, por exemplo, ao digitar 333,333,333, as virgulas fossem adicionadas automaticamente a cada três números. Eu consegui fazer isso utilizando o Cleaver.js e o Autonumeric.js, mas eles bugam tudo na hora da soma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para inserir as vírgulas:**

```
function addCommas(event) {
    event.value = event.value.replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}
```

**Para somar os valores depois:**

```
function removeCommas(valueWithCommas   ) {
    return +valueWithCommas.replace(/,/g, '');
}
```

A função **addCommas** podes utilizar no *onkeyup* e a função **removeCommas** nos elementos antes de fazer a soma dos teus valores em tua função de calcular.

Não é necessário o *onkeydown* e *onmouseout*. O *onkeyup* já é suficiente.
Esta solução abordada foi com javascript puro, indepente de frameworks.

Bons estudos!

```js
function changeValue(event) {
 event.value = addCommas(event.value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
 calculate();
}

function addCommas(value) {
        return value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}

function calculate() {
 const dve = removeCommas(document.querySelector('#dve').value);
 const ds = removeCommas(document.querySelector('#ds').value);
 const divergence = document.querySelector('#dinheiroDivergencia');
 divergence.value = addCommas(`${dve + ds}`);
}

function removeCommas(valueWithCommas) {
 return +valueWithCommas.replace(/,/g, '');
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <b>Dinheiro</b>
   </td>
   <!-- Dinheiro - Valor Encontrado -->
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dve" value="0" onkeyup="changeValue(this)"/>
   </td>
   <!-- Dinheiro - Sistema -->
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ds" value="0" onkeyup="changeValue(this)"/>
   </td>
   <!-- Dinheiro - Divergência -->
   <td>
    <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" id="dinheiroDivergencia" disabled> 
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Olá Gabriel, escolha alguma das respostas como a melhor, caso tenha resolvido o teu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Editando minha resposta original, você já utiliza o Cleave.JS.

No Cleave.JS há a opção de você pegar o número RAW ou Formatted, além de definir qual será o separador de casas decimais.

Veja o meu exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ricardozambon/xfbakc68

Adicionei o separador decimal, e ao trazer o resultado, troco para o ponto e recupero no JavaScript.

Claro que tudo isso depende bastante de qual o Front-end pretende utilizar.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado!